# Is there a (deep) copy constructor for pybind11::array_t?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have an existing `pybind11::array_t`, and need to do a copy-construction. Is there a function inside `pybind11` that allows me to do a deep copy of an `array_t`?

I know that I could create a new `array_t`, size it properly, and then copy the original data into it, but was wondering if there exists already a method to do this that hides these passages.

Comment: are you sure `auto copy = original;` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Yes, because that involves a shallow copy. 
This snippet prints the same addresses: 
 `using py_arr = pybind11::array_t<double>;  
py_arr a;
auto b = a;
std::cout << b.data() << " " << a.data() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

the default copy constructor does a deep copy, [people are actually trying to avoid this](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/323) :)

To use the copy constructor, you can go through the `buffer`

```cpp
using py_arr = pybind11::array_t<double>;
py_arr a;

// do stuff with a, fill it and everything...

auto buffer = a.request(); 
py_arr b = py_arr(buffer);

std::cout << b.data() << " " << a.data() << std::endl; // this won't return the same address twice
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

(a)  I agree on the buffer option. However, the ```request``` is a const method, so in case you have a function somewhere that accepts ```const pybind11::array_t & a```, and one would want to create a deep copy of it, one would need to ```const_cast```. That is why I was asking for deep copy constructor or similar method. 
 
(2) The default copy constructor of ```py::array_t``` does a **shallow** copy. 
```using py_arr = pybind11::array_t<double>;  py_arr a; py_arr b(a); std::cout << b.data() << " " << a.data() << std::endl;``` prints the same address.

Comment: If there is no other option, I could use the buffer but I was hoping for an alternative, more compact way that works for const-cases too.

Comment: Oh I see, you could overload the `=` operator (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421715/3283333)) with the implementation I just gave, that should sort you out right ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply :) Yes, I could overload that but then it would break the semantics. There are places where I need shallow copy and places where I need deep copy. I think i I will just use the buffer, even though I have to ```const_cast```. Thanks for your help!